# nhibernate: simple template project

Tags: nhibernate

I have been using NHibernate for a few years, but whenever I have a question I find myself in the situation of "it would take me 8h to build a sample app/adapt my business-code before I can ask a question".

Is there a simple Visual Studio project out there (maybe even including something like "AbstractDomainObject") to download which one can reference?

Cheers, Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sharp Architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/) is a good place to start as it "provides a solid architectural foundation for rapidly building maintainable web applications leveraging the ASP.NET MVC framework with NHibernate." The [Sharp Architecture zip files](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/downloads) can be found at GitHub.

Another possibility would be use to the [.NET Reference App](http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-reference-app/) which is used in [Headspring's](http://www.headspring.com/) Agile Boot Camp training.

Finally, the [example source code](http://www.manning.com/palermo2/aspnetmvc2inaction_code.zip) provided with [ASP.NET MVC in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193518279X) could also be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at these projects and post back my experiences!

Comment: After looking through the referenced projects I decided to create my own reference project, because it resembles my use case better. Have a look at it under [GitHub: https://github.com/draptik/nhibernate-nunit](https://github.com/draptik/nhibernate-nunit). Comments are appreciated ;-)